# Determine the contrapositive of this statement:

Tags: real-analysis, logic

> For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, if the sum $x + y$ is rational, then $x$ is rational and $y$ is rational.

My attempt at answer this:

$p$ = "if the sum $x+y$ is rational"

$q$ = "then $x$ is rational and $y$ is rational"

The contrapositive is $\sim q \Rightarrow \sim p$

So...

For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x$ is not rational and $y$ is not rational, then the sum $x+y$ is not rational.

Assuming this correct, would this be a true statement?

Comment: Remember that the negation of "and" is "or".  Your final question is confusing as it has the word "this" in it twice referring to two different phrases.

Comment: In your answer, in the hypothesis, it should be **or**, not **and**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake:

Lets denote $p$ and $q$ the statements like you did.

Then $\text{not } q$ is "$x$ is irrational **OR** $y$ is irrational".

The negation of "or" is "and", and the negation of "and" is "or".

And $\text{not }p$ is "the sum $x+y$ is irrational".

Finally the statement is false because you can take $x=\pi$ $y=-\pi$ which verifies the statement $\text{not }q$, but not the statement $\text{not }p$ because $\pi-\pi=0$ which is rational.

Comment: I understand that I missed the OR, but I don't understand why you changed rational to irrational if we added the not?  If it is NOT rational, then it is irrational, right?

Comment: Exactly. NOT(A and B)=NOT(A) or NOT(B). Like you said, being not rational is the same as being irrational.

Comment: So if I just replace AND with OR in my above attempt, then that is correct?